# Can we detect and measure color charge?

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, confinement, color-charge

I was listening to the "Why This Universe" podcast about dark matter and Dr. Dan Hooper mentioned briefly that electric and color charge can be readily detected.  Can color charge be detected and measured, both locally (here on Earth) and in distant galaxies?

Comment: Due to confinement, there are no macroscopic/free color-charged objects, so I'm not sure what sort of "detection" we're talking about here. For most purposes, a paper with "No charge" written on it is a perfect "color charge detector".

Answer (score 1):

It is not helpful practice to talk about electric and color charges in the same breath, except to contrast them with extreme prejudice.

Electric forces are macroscopic and so you may detect electric charges at large distances, but color forces are nonexistent/meaningless at distances longer than a fermi: they are microscopic. So you can barely expect to "observe"  the interaction of two colored objects at even nuclear, let alone atomic, distances.

You may only ***infer*** color interactions from the signatures of colorless objects (hadrons) in the lab/detector: all of particle physics detections probe our understanding of hadronic interactions by comparing them to models for such, based on color interactions at subfermi distances. The predictions are so good that such models have risen to the level of elegant and powerful theories: QCD.

The reason color charges cannot interact at large distances is because of the fundamental dynamical behavior of them, [***color confinement***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_confinement), that is the inexorable rapid increase in energy of two colored objects from a colorless grouping smaller than a few fermis, if you attempted to separate them, to distances of a few fermis; huge forces require the input of sufficiently high energies to enable the creation of a bevy of colorless objects some of which are detected.

A glib  simile for  such high-energy scattering events  is the hyper-energetic collision of two cars: instead of observing car components flying out of the collision, (as you might in atomic or nuclear physics), you actually observe motorcycles, cars, tractors, sewing machines, pumpkins, watermelons,..., flying off.

Elaborate physical calculations for such processes *work quite well*,  affording physicists confidence that the underlying QCD theories and techniques are basically right.  They work at the detectors of accelerator labs, cosmic ray detectors, but also at the level of reconstructing the early universe landscape, and the ensuing predictions for early universe processes influencing galactic phenomena.

Comment: I wouldn't expect to see (or detect) a color charged particle any more than I'd expect to see an individual electron.  Might there be some other way to detect, on a macro scale, that such particles are present.

Comment: As I explained, on a macro scale there *cannot be colored particles*. You can identify them colorless hadrons in your detector, which contain confined colored constituents, but you can't detect something which does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Color charge requires a detector probe than can *look into* the insides of a hadron. Because of how very small a hadron is, the wavelength of that probe has to be very *very* small- so small that the only way we have to produce that probe is in a big particle accelerator.

Because energy goes up as wavelength goes down, that probe is energetic enough to blast the hadron apart, and we then detect the color charge of the remains that come flying out and deduce what charges were inside the hadron before we blew it up. So "color charge" is something that is manifest only inside hadrons; it is not communicated over large distances like electromagnetism is.

Comment: Thanks. I certainly understand that gluons have a very short lifetime, but why is that related to mass?  And is the "short range" simply because they don't live long enough to travel further?

Comment: @PM2Ring  Gluons are massless, but apparently account for 99% of the mass of the proton.  Figure that one out.   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_chromodynamics_binding_energy#:~:text=Quantum%20chromodynamics%20binding%20energy%20(QCD,most%20of%20the%20hadron%27s%20mass.

Comment: @foolishmuse Frank Wilczek, who won a Nobel for his work on QCD, has some great articles on his site. http://www.frankwilczek.com/core.html In particular, see *The Origin of Mass*.

Comment: @PM2Ring  Thanks for that.  Next Monday I'll be attending day 1 of the new Vancouver Quantum Gravity Institute conference  Quantum Mechanics & Gravity: Marrying Theory & Experiment.  http://conference.quantumgravityinstitute.ca/schedule/   I hope to pick up some ideas.

Comment: @foolishmuse Nice! That's a pretty impressive lineup of speakers. :)

Comment: @pm2ring, thanks for that, will edit. -NN